# Can i pass data from one VSTS extension to another extension?

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-extensions

I got to know that Azure Devops provides services to store data from an extension, using getValue() and setValue().

Using it i was able to create an extension "A" which stores value.

How to retrieve the same data from another extension "B"?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, but the easiest way (and that is IF your extension "A" is written in PowerShell) is to use this line of code example:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"
```

You can then pass the variable into the next script using: `$(testvar)`

But this is available only in that environment where it is created and not in the subsequent environments.  But you can invoke RM rest APIs to update the release to set a variable from environment 1 and that variable should be available in environment 2 once the environment 2 starts. Here is a sample on how you can update a release and do let us know in case it does not work for you.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2016/05/23/how-to-update-release-level-variables-using-rm-rest-apis/